# Should i use EL 2.2 with Java EE 5/Tomcat 6.0.29? Server or app upgrade?

Tags: java, jsp, el

The questions are:

1) Should i use EL 2.2 with Java EE 5 / Tomcat 6.0.29?

I know it works, the question is if there is any technical problem in such upgrade or if it is not recommended.

2) Server or app upgrade?

I have it my app with this configuration in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I followed this approach because i have lots of servers and do not want to upgrade libraries in all of them. Is this way worst than upgrading in server installations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't forsee any issues with this approach. I would even prefer it above touching a default server library setup. You may for instance overlook it when installing a new server instance in the future. Controlling the libs from the webapp side on is perfectly fine. You only need to know what you're doing. For example, when supplying outdated libs, but not configuring the `web.xml`, may lead to classloading collisions and result in abstract errors, but that would manifest soon enough at local dev environment anyway.